# Python 2.7 pySerial read() returns all characters in Python interpreter but not Python script. Also need robust way to read until buffer is empty

Tags: python-2.7, pyserial

I am communicating with a microcontroller that automatically initializes its flash memory whenever you open its serial port. So on a serial port read, the microcontroller prints up to 10,000 bytes of data showing the addresses and their initial values. You need to leave the port open for the entirety of the print to ensure that initialization completed. I don't ever perform any writes, just reads.

I modified the pySerial buffer from 4k to 32k since I do not want any breaks between reads (subsequent reads will simply restart the init cycle). Below is a snippet of my code where I read from the microcontroller serial port. When I run this snippet from the interpreter, I can tell from print and sizeof that temp contains all 9956 bytes. However when I run the py file, I get only 296 bytes. I inserted the sleep() method after read() but this did not have any effect. I cannot tell from the microcontroller if the initialization completed.

Is there a robust way to read until the serial buffer is empty? The microcontroller image is application-specific, so I cannot always predict the required read() size or timeout.

Any ideas what I could try? I've searched other threads but haven't found anything specific to this problem.

```
# Create serial port instance
self.ser_port = serial.Serial()
self.ser_port.port = 0
self.ser_port.timeout = 0
.
.
.
self.ser_port.open()
time.sleep(1)
temp = self.ser_port.read(32768)
time.sleep(4)
self.ser_port.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A timeout of 0 tells pySerial to return immediately with whatever data is already available.  If you want `read()` to wait to allow more data to come in, use a non-zero timeout.

The first `sleep()` could cause you to lose some of the data that comes in after `open` but before `read`, because the internal buffer might not be as big as the buffer you are passing to `read()`.  But that is highly application-dependent -- if the device you are communicating with takes awhile after the open() to respond, then it might not be a problem.

The second `sleep()` does nothing for you, because the `read()` is already finished at that point.

Note that the timeout value is the *maximum total* amount of time to wait.  `read()` will return when it has filled its buffer, or it has been this long after it was called, whichever comes first.

Here is some example code that will return under the following circumstances:

a) 10-12 seconds with no data

b) 2-4 silent seconds after last data returned, if at least 100 bytes was received

```
self.ser_port = serial.Serial()
self.ser_port.port = 0
self.ser_port.timeout = 2
.
.
.

self.ser_port.open()
timeout_count = 0
received = []
data_count = 0
while 1:
    buffer = self.ser_port.read(32768)
    if buffer:
        received.append(buffer)
        data_count += len(buffer)
        timeout_count = 0
        continue
    if data_count > 100:
        # Break if we received at least 100 bytes of data,
        # and haven't received any data for at least 2 seconds
        break
    timeout_count += 1
    if timeout_count >= 5:
        # Break if we haven't received any data for at
        # least 10 seconds, even if we never received
        # any data
        break

    received = ''.join(received)  # If you need all the data
```

Depending on your microcontroller, you may be able to reduce these timeout values considerably, and still have a fairly robust solution for retrieving all the startup data from the microcontroller.